# A method for reducing an ideal $\langle f(x),g(x)\rangle$ to a principal ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra

We know that $\Bbb R[x]$ is a Principal Ideal Domain. Hence, for every two polynomials $f(x),g(x)\in\Bbb R[x]$, there exists a third polynomial $h(x)$ such that
$$\langle f(x),g(x)\rangle = \langle h(x)\rangle.$$
I am wondering if we can express $h(x)$ explicitly.

> Is there a formula for $h(x)$ in terms of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$?

We know that $h(x)=f(x)a(x)+g(x)b(x)$ for some polynomials $a,b$, and $f(x)=h(x)\alpha(x)$ and $g(x)=h(x)\beta(x)$ for some other polynomials $\alpha,\beta$. But this leads to nowhere.

> For example, if $f(x)\in\Bbb R[x]$, what is $\langle x^2,f(x)\rangle$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor#Euclidean_algorithm I'm not sure if this counts as a "formula" in the sense you want.

Comment: or use a robot http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=GCD+%7Bx%5E2%2Bx%5E3%2Cx%5E2%2Bx%5E3%2Bx%5E4%7D

Comment: $h(x)=\gcd(f(x),g(x))$. It can be determined by *Euclid's algorithm*.